# source in every Dockerfile RUN call

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, ros

I have a Dockerfile, where I am finding myself constantly needing to call `source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash`.

e.g.:

```
RUN source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash \
    && SOME_COMMAND

RUN source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash \
    && SOME_OTHER_COMMAND
```

Is there a method to have this initialised in every `RUN` call in a Dockerfile?

Have tried adding to `~/.bash_profile` and Docker's `ENV` command with no luck.

Comment: I tried to answer, I failed. Short answer: Nope. Long answer: Write a wrapper script if this looks too ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** what you want is feasible by copying your `.sh` script in `/etc/profile.d/` and using the `SHELL` Dockerfile command to tweak the default shell.

### Details:

To start with, consider the following sample script `setup.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
echo "# setup.sh"
ENV_VAR="some value"
some_fun() {
    echo "## some_fun"
}
```

Then, it can be noted that bash provides the `--login` CLI option:

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The `--noprofile` option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When an interactive login shell exits, or a non-interactive login shell executes the exit builtin command, Bash reads and executes commands from the file `~/.bash_logout`, if it exists.
>
> − https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Furthermore, instead of appending the `setup.sh` code in `/etc/profile`, you can take advantage of the `/etc/profile.d` folder that is read in the following way by most distributions:

```bash
$ docker run --rm -i debian:10 cat /etc/profile | tail -n 9

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Note in particular that the `.sh` extension is mandatory, hence the naming of the minimal-working-example above: `setup.sh` (not `setup.bash`).

Finally, it is possible to rely on the [`SHELL` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell) to replace the default shell used by `RUN` (in place of `["/bin/sh", "-c"]`) to incorporate the `--login` option of `bash`.

Concretely, you could phrase your `Dockerfile` like this:

```dockerfile
FROM debian:10

# WORKDIR /opt/ros/noetic
# COPY setup.sh .
# RUN . /opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh && echo "ENV_VAR=$ENV_VAR"

# empty var here
RUN echo "ENV_VAR=$ENV_VAR"

# enable the extra shell init code
COPY setup.sh /etc/profile.d/

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]

# nonempty var and function
RUN echo "ENV_VAR=$ENV_VAR" && some_fun

# DISABLE the extra shell init code!
RUN rm /etc/profile.d/setup.sh

# empty var here
RUN echo "ENV_VAR=$ENV_VAR"
```

Outcome:

```
$ docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.144kB
Step 1/7 : FROM debian:10
 ---> ef05c61d5112
Step 2/7 : RUN echo "ENV_VAR=$ENV_VAR"
 ---> Running in 87b5c589ec60
ENV_VAR=
Removing intermediate container 87b5c589ec60
 ---> 6fdb70be76f9
Step 3/7 : COPY setup.sh /etc/profile.d/
 ---> e6aab4ebf9ef
Step 4/7 : SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]
 ---> Running in d73b0d13df23
Removing intermediate container d73b0d13df23
 ---> ccbe789dc36d
Step 5/7 : RUN echo "ENV_VAR=$ENV_VAR" && some_fun
 ---> Running in 42fd1ae14c17
# setup.sh
ENV_VAR=some value
## some_fun
Removing intermediate container 42fd1ae14c17
 ---> de74831896a4
Step 6/7 : RUN rm /etc/profile.d/setup.sh
 ---> Running in bdd969a63def
# setup.sh
Removing intermediate container bdd969a63def
 ---> 5453be3271e5
Step 7/7 : RUN echo "ENV_VAR=$ENV_VAR"
 ---> Running in 0712cea427f1
ENV_VAR=
Removing intermediate container 0712cea427f1
 ---> 216a421f5659
Successfully built 216a421f5659
Successfully tagged test:latest
```