# Dockerfile RUN command stops working after ROS install

Tags: docker, ros

I am installing ROS as instructed at http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu in a dockerfile.  After installing, you set up the environment with 'source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash'.  However, after I do that, every RUN command in the dockerfile stops working correctly.

In the dockerfile below, the first 'ls /' produces the expected output, but the second one does not.  This is not specific to 'ls', that's just a demo of the problem;  every command I RUN after the ROS environment does not have the effect expected.  What is happening in the ROS environment setup to break it and how do I prevent it?  I have a lot of other setup that needs to happen after setting up ROS.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y lsb-release && apt-get clean all
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg2

# Set timezone so tzdata is not interactive during install
ENV TZ=America/New_York
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

# Install ROS, from http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654 && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt install -qq -y ros-noetic-ros-base

RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN python3 -m pip install rospkg

RUN echo "source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc

# This DOES produce what you would think
RUN ls /

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source ~/.bashrc"]

# This DOES NOT produce what you would think
RUN ls /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dockerfile [`SHELL`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell) directive changes the shell that's used to interpret `RUN` commands.  The default is `["/bin/sh", "-c"]`, so you get

```sh
# These two commands are identical with the default SHELL
RUN ls /
RUN ["/bin/sh", "-c", "ls /"]
```

When you write `SHELL` as you've done, you instead get

```sh
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source ~/.bashrc"]
RUN ls /
# Equivalently:
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source ~/.bashrc", "ls /"]
```

However, the `sh -c` option reads a *single* command word and executes it; any further options are ignored (mostly; the command word sees them as `$1` positional parameters).

Mostly in Docker, shell dotfiles like `.bashrc` are completely ignored.  Setting up environment variables using `ENV` directives is better.  For the single main container process, you can also use an entrypoint wrapper script to load a file of variables, but this doesn't work during the container build or in `docker exec` debug shells.

You can possibly take advantage of `sh -c`'s specific semantics, and knowing the command will be passed as a single additional argument, and say

```sh
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", ". ~/.bashrc && $1"]
```

[source in every Dockerfile RUN call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907049/source-in-every-dockerfile-run-call) instead [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921735/10008173):

```sh
# Tell bash these are "login" shells and _should_ read shell dotfiles
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]
```